# FFmpeg: Failed to create drawbox filter with max thickness

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I've switched from FFmpeg version 1.2. to the last 2.5 release. After changing all deprecated methods I ran into a problem with a drawbox filter. In version 1.2 I could define a filled box with the following settings (see [FFmpeg Filter Documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox)):

```
strFilterDesc += "drawbox=x=0:y="+height+":w="+width+":h=50:color=0xeeeeee@0.4:t=max,
```

When I start the application, I receive the following errors:

```
[Parsed_drawbox_2 @ 0x79e9a0] [Eval @ 0x7fffb57f8e70] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'max'
[Parsed_drawbox_2 @ 0x75f0a0] Error when evaluating the expression 'max'.
[Parsed_drawtext_1 @ 0x759be0] Failed to configure input pad on Parsed_drawbox_2
```

Can someone give me a hint what I'm doing wrong here? Even with the example of the documentation the same error occurs. Is there an other way to create a filled box?

### Edit:

Here's the content of `stfFilterDesc`:

> drawtext=fontfile=./fonts/truetype/freefont/HelveticaNeue.ttf: text='foo': x=5: y=5: shadowx=0: shadowy=0: fontsize=12: fontcolor=0xeeeeee@1.0: box=0: boxcolor=0xeeeeee@0.5, drawbox=x=0:y=490:w=960:h=50:color=0xeeeeee@0.4:t=max, drawtext=fontfile=./fonts/truetype/freefont/HelveticaNeue.ttf: text='foo': x=32:y=(h-text_h-25): fontsize=16: fontcolor=0x333333@1.0: box=0: boxcolor=0xeeeeee@0.4, drawtext=fontfile=./fonts/truetype/freefont/HelveticaNeue.ttf: text='foo': x=32:y=(h-text_h-10): fontsize=14: fontcolor=0x333333@1.0: box=0: boxcolor=0xeeeeee@0.4

Comment: Could you print the `strFilterDesc` so we see the actual value given to FFMPEG ?

Comment: The full desc looks like: drawtext=fontfile=./fonts/truetype/freefont/HelveticaNeue.ttf: text='foo': x=5: y=5: shadowx=0: shadowy=0: fontsize=12: fontcolor=0xeeeeee@1.0: box=0: boxcolor=0xeeeeee@0.5, drawbox=x=0:y=490:w=960:h=50:color=0xeeeeee@0.4:t=max, drawtext=fontfile=./fonts/truetype/freefont/HelveticaNeue.ttf: text='foo': x=32:y=(h-text_h-25): fontsize=16: fontcolor=0x333333@1.0: box=0: boxcolor=0xeeeeee@0.4, drawtext=fontfile=./fonts/truetype/freefont/HelveticaNeue.ttf: text='foo': x=32:y=(h-text_h-10): fontsize=14: fontcolor=0x333333@1.0: box=0: boxcolor=0xeeeeee@0.4

Comment: Try to split your request and iterate one by one to see which one is messing with FFMPEG

Comment: Its the t=max, because max seems to be unknown

Comment: This is likely either a bug in drawbox or in the documentation. Reported as bug [#4332: Expression 'max' no longer works with t option in drawbox](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4332). Until it gets fixed you can use an appropriate numerical value.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard : Thanks for creating the report!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encountered a bug: [#4332 – Expression 'max' no longer works with t option in drawbox](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4332).

This was fixed today (2015 March 2) with commit [047fd98](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=commitdiff;h=047fd986bf3641ad3dc137746097271c339ee5f0):

```
commit 047fd986bf3641ad3dc137746097271c339ee5f0
Author: Michael Niedermayer
Date:   Mon Mar 2 02:32:55 2015 +0100

    avfilter/vf_drawbox: Fix handling of max values

    Fixes Ticket4332

    Signed-off-by: Michael Niedermayer
```

So you will need to [compile](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) or [get a recent build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) to take advantage of this bug fix. The various static builds available via the [FFmpeg download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html) page are updated regularly.